# Application.OnKey Ctrl Shift 0

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to tie macro to a key combinations in Excel 2010 (v14.0).

In the `ThisWorkbook` code I've:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^+1", "Foo"
    Application.OnKey "^+0", "Bar"
End Sub
```

In the `Module1` code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
    MsgBox "hello"
End Sub

Sub bar()
    MsgBox "world"
End Sub
```

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> Excel says "hello".
When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> Excel does **not** say "world".

I cannot get `Application.OnKey` to work with ^+0 for any macro. Is there a way to do this? Why doesn't the code above work?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jeeped's answer:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> unhides columns in Excel 2016. C hides them.

And you could substitute the following in Jeeped's code:

`Commandbars("Column").Controls("Unhide").Execute`.

Don't know that it's any improvement over `EntireColumn.Hidden = False`, but what the heck.

Answer (score 0):

You are equating the built-in menu commands with custom sub procedures. They are not interchangeable with the [Application.OnKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx) method but a custom macro can easily be created that duplicates the built-in command's functionality.

In a module code sheet:

```
Sub myUnHideColumns()
    With Selection
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        'alternate toggle visible/hidden
        '.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not .EntireColumn.Hidden
    End With
End Sub

Sub myHotKeys()
    Application.OnKey "^+0", "myUnHideColumns"
End Sub
```

In your case you would want to move the affecting code from `myHotKeys` to your [Workbook_Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242003(v=office.12).aspx) event macro.

Comment: You completely ignored my question and instructed me to do something that doesn't work. "Is there a trick to Ctrl+Shift+0? Is it completely unavailable? Why?"

Comment: Sorry to hear that you were not able to implement this. I do not post untested code. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I'd be very interested to know about your system configuration, because I implemented exactly what you said on 3 different computers and it worked on none of them.